# Object level ACL for bulk GET operation REST API

Tags: python, flask, acl

I am trying to implement an ACL with object level granularity such that a bulk GET request returns only permitted objects. In other words, I have a resource *A* which can be obtained using an endpoint `/api/v1/A`. A GET request returns a list of *A* type resources. I want to now introduce an ACL such that only those resource objects are returned for which the principal has read permission. Any design suggestions are greatly appreciated!